# How can I set different xtick labels for each subplot when plotting with subplots parameter of pandas plot function?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

This question was written in Jupyter notebook.

How can I set different xtick labels for each subplot when plotting with `subplots` parameter of pandas `plot` function?

here is my dataset

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'col1': [10, 20, 30], 'col2': [20, 30, 40], 'col3': [40, 20, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    10    20    40
1    20    30    20
2    30    40    10
```

my plot with pandas `plot`

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
ax1 = df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=False, figsize=(6, 8), color=colors)
```

**ax1**

[image]

---

> Question

I would like to assign separate xticklabels to each subplot using the variable `idxs`, as below code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# each xtick_label
idxs = [pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03']), 
        pd.to_datetime(['2022-04-04', '2022-04-05', '2022-04-06']), 
        pd.to_datetime(['2023-05-10', '2023-05-11', '2023-05-12'])]

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, 0):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, i + 1)
    df[col].set_axis(idxs[i]).plot(color=colors[i])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

[image]

I am looking for a way to do this either in code that generates `ax1` or in result of `ax1`.

Additionally, if you know of any functionality in pandas `plot` function same as `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)`, please let me know.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thank you for all the helpful answers!

Answer (score 2):

The method `pandas.DataFrame.plot` can receive a parameter called `ax`. It is a `matplot` object, so you will have an extra work to do that. Find the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = {'col1': [10, 20, 30], 'col2': [20, 30, 40], 'col3': [40, 20, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(6, 8))

plt.sca(axes[0])
plt.xticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], color='blue')
plt.sca(axes[1])
plt.xticks([0.0, 1.0, 2.0], color='green')
plt.sca(axes[2])
plt.xticks([x * 0.25 for x in range(0, 12)], color='red')

df.plot(subplots=True, ax=axes, legend=False, sharex=False);
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: Good answer.  Some remarks: Instead of `plt.sca(axes[0])`and `plt.xticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], color='blue')`, just writing `axes[0].set_xticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], color='blue')` would be clearer. Also, in general, it is recommended first to do the plotting and afterward changing the ticks etc. Some plotting functions can change ticks and other properties.

Comment: To only change the color, you can use `axes[0].tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='blue')`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I would like to implement mapping x ticks to datetime like my second graph using pandas `plot`.

Comment: You can use the same thecnique, but passing dates instead. You can use whatever you want. `plt.xticks(["X", "is", 42, "and", "2024-02-23"], color='blue')`.